# Stacked/nested/multiple modals in ng2-bootstrap

Tags: angular, typescript, ng2-bootstrap

I have a modal within a modal, and it mostly works, except for one thing. The backdrop hangs behind the modal that is already open. I checked the documentation, and I'm not sure how to specify exactly where the backdrop should go. The API shows `ModalBackdropComponent`, with a selector of `bs-modal-backdrop`, but I'm not sure if there is something I can do with this to solve my issue. I'm not sure if this is a z-index issue, or if the backdrop needs to be placed somewhere specific.

Comment: Suggest you to have a look at this [**answer**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42460418/angular-2-ng2-bootstrap-parent-component-call-modal-show-in-child-component-n/42463516#42463516) will enhance based on your requirement. Reply back.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ran into this exact problem today. I couldn't find any way to resolve it by explicitly defining my own instance of the `bs-modal-backdrop` component. The way I resolved it was to set `[config]="{ backdrop: false }"` on the `bsModal` element of the child modal (disable the default backdrop), then I added a new element like this:

```
<div class="modal-backdrop fade in" (click)="modal.hide()"></div>
```

As the first element inside the child modal `bsModal` element. This assumes you've defined the `modal` property as `#modal="bs-modal"` or similar. Alternatively you could call a method on your component with the click handler.

You'll also need to set a z-index on the `.modal-dialog` element (which should be a sibling of the new `.modal-backgrop` element) of `1050` or greater.

Comment: thank you for your solution. However I had to manualy set the opacity style of the newly added backdrop to a value greater than zero. Otherwise the new backdrop would remain invisible.

Answer (score 2):

With ngx-boostrap, you have no control over the classes of the `modal-container` or `bs-modal-backdrop`, unfortunately. Nor does there seem to be a way of adding a new element as a sibling of `.modal-dialog`.

But you can style the nested/child `modal-container`. The `modal-container`s are added sequentially to the DOM. You could use an `:nth-of-type` CSS selector to style the child `modal-container` so that its background, which includes the parent modal, is faded.

```
modal-container:nth-of-type(2) {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In global css file (`styles.css`):

```
modal-container+modal-container {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```