# Angular 2 ng2-bootstrap modal inside child component called from parent component

Tags: angular, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal, ng2-bootstrap

Hard to explain this. I had a simple working ng2-bootstrap modal example working. I expanded it to include Boostrap 4 Jumbotron example template for my home page, now the ng2-bootstrap modal does nothing. I can see the `this.childModal.show()` in **child modal component is getting called on the button click, but nothing happens. No error in Chrome console and no modal shows.** I have no idea what to do next :-/

```
// ============================================================================
// /src/app/app.module.ts

import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { ModalModule } from 'ng2-bootstrap/modal';
import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { DemoModalChildComponent } from './demo-modal-child.component';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        AppComponent, DemoModalChildComponent
    ],
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        FormsModule,
        HttpModule,
        NgbModule.forRoot(),
        ModalModule.forRoot()
    ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }


// ============================================================================
// /src/app/app.component.ts

import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
    title = 'app works!';
}



<!-- ========================================================================== -->
<!-- /src/app/app.component.html -->

<nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-md navbar-inverse fixed-top bg-inverse">
    <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarsExampleDefault"
        aria-controls="navbarsExampleDefault" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarsExampleDefault">
            <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                <li class="nav-item active">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="/home">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" (click)="showLoginModal()">Login</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="/members">Players</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="/game">Game</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="http://example.com" id="dropdown01" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true"
                        aria-expanded="false">Dropdown
                        </a>
                        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdown01">
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                        </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
                <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" placeholder="Search">
                <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
            </form>
        </div>
</nav>

<!-- Main jumbotron for a primary marketing message or call to action -->
<div class="jumbotron">
    <div class="container">
        <demo-modal-child #c="child"></demo-modal-child>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="c.showChildModal()">Open child modal</button>
        <h1 class="display-3">Hello, world!</h1>
        <p>This is a template for a simple marketing or informational website. It includes a large callout called a jumbotron
            and three supporting pieces of content. Use it as a starting point to create something more unique.</p>
        <p><a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="#" role="button">Learn more &raquo;</a></p>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- /jumbotron -->

<div class="container">
    <!-- Example row of columns -->
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <h2>Heading</h2>
            <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum
                nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed
                odio dui.
            </p>
            <p><a class="btn btn-secondary" href="#" role="button">View details &raquo;</a></p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <h2>Heading</h2>
            <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum
                nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed
                odio dui. </p>
            <p><a class="btn btn-secondary" href="#" role="button">View details &raquo;</a></p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <h2>Heading</h2>
            <p>Donec sed odio dui. Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Vestibulum id ligula porta felis
                euismod semper. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa
                justo sit amet risus.</p>
            <p><a class="btn btn-secondary" href="#" role="button">View details &raquo;</a></p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <hr>

    <footer>
        <p>&copy; burnmarkGames 2017</p>
    </footer>
</div>
<!-- /container -->


// ============================================================================
// /src/app/demo-modal-child.component.ts

import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { ModalDirective } from 'ng2-bootstrap/modal';

@Component({
    selector: 'demo-modal-child',
    templateUrl: './demo-modal-child.component.html',
    exportAs: 'child'
})
export class DemoModalChildComponent {
    @ViewChild('childModal') public childModal: ModalDirective;

    public showChildModal(): void {
        console.log('DemoModalChildComponent.showChildModal fired!');
        this.childModal.show();
    }

    public hideChildModal(): void {
        this.childModal.hide();
    }
}


<!-- ========================================================================== -->
<!-- /src/app/demo-modal-child.component.html -->

<div bsModal #childModal="bs-modal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog"
    aria-labelledby="mySmallModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4 class="modal-title pull-left">Please login...</h4>
                <button type="button" class="close pull-right" aria-label="Close" (click)="hideChildModal()">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                I am a child modal, opened from parent component!
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you are calling **modal.show()** in your child component. which is your is your parent component?

Comment: @Aravind There is html/code in the middle of app.component.html ( `<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="c.showChildModal()">Open child modal</button>` ) calls the childModal show(). Thanks for any help my friend :-)

Comment: @Aravind I might not have answered your question: `app.component.ts` is the parent.

Comment: Hey dude, have a look at my answer below.. lemme know if you need anything else

Comment: @Aravind Thank you for the example! I've studied the code in plunker. This is my assumption right now, please correct me if I'm wrong: I have several different modals that need to be separate components so they can be shared among several different parent components. I don't think this code supports that as I'd have to put all the different templates in the AppComponent template somehow. Am I thinking right? :-)

Comment: you can use my code to use it as a generic modal and add different modal-body for different components. I have clearly explained in the last two lines.

Comment: do you need some more improvement on the answer?

Comment: @Aravind If the AppComponent below was say LoginModalComponent, how would that change the code? I'd need to use the child modal(s) in a HomeComponent parent.

Comment: Yes exactly. Have your common-modal component separately. Reuse it in the login modal component. Create home component which will have login modal as a child.

Comment: did my answer solved your requirement ? or need further help

Comment: @Aravind Yes your advice has helped very much. Thank you Aravind! :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your common child modal component will be as below

```
import {Component,Input, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';
import { ModalDirective } from 'ng2-bootstrap/ng2-bootstrap';

@Component({
  selector: 'common-modal',
  template: `
   <div bsModal #childModal="bs-modal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="mySmallModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title pull-left">{{title}}</h4>
        <button type="button" class="close pull-right" aria-label="Close" (click)="hideChildModal()">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <ng-content select=".modal-body"> </ng-content>
      </div>

      <div class="modal-footer">
        <div class="pull-left">
          <button class="btn btn-default" (click)="hide()"> Cancel </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
  `,
})
export class CommonModalComponent {
   @ViewChild('childModal') public childModal:ModalDirective;
   @Input() title:string;
  constructor() {
  }
  show(){
    this.childModal.show();
  }
  hide(){
    this.childModal.hide();
  }
}
```

Using the child component in your parent component will look as below

```
import {Component, ViewChild, NgModule,ViewContainerRef} from '@angular/core'
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { ModalDirective,ModalModule } from 'ng2-bootstrap/ng2-bootstrap';
import {CommonModalComponent} from './child.modal';
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="childModal.show()">Open modal</button>
    <common-modal  #childModal [title]="'common modal'"> 
    <div class="modal-body">
    Hi heloo </div>
    </common-modal> 

  `,
})
export class AppComponent {
  @ViewChild('childModal') childModal :CommonModalComponent;
  constructor(private viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef) {
  }

}
```

Using the above code you can have a separate common modal dialog which can be reused, so that your header & footer remains the same and you can use **Content-Projection** to use change the body of the modal dialog.

**[LIVE DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/t4JwdewzXXBrnQRV6QMe?p=preview)**