# ngx-modal - Angular 2

Tags: angular, ngx-modal

I am trying to implement modal form in my angular application. My code looks alright to me as i do not see any error. I have installed ngx-modal into my application and i have also imported the `ModalModule` in my `app.module.ts` file. What could be the reason why the modal form is not responding?

```ts
<button class="btn btn-success"  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open</button>

<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">

          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

### app.module.ts

```ts
import {ModalModule} from 'ngx-modal';

imports: [          
        ModalModule,
],
```

Comment: why **ngx-modal** preferred over **ng2-modal** ? any specific reason?

Comment: the ng2-modal is deprecated

Comment: what is the reason can you elaborate, I guess it has everything in it.

Comment: I don't get your question. Sorry? Are you refering to why i said ng2-modal is deprecated? if so, when i was installing ng2-modal, the terminal threw a warning that ng2-modal had deprecated and that, i should install ngx-modal instead

Comment: yes. exactly.  why you said ng2-modal is deprecated? also what is superior in the ngx-modal over ng2-modal??

Comment: I don't really know what makes ngx-modal superior. I basically thought since ng2-modal is deprecated, it won't function well with my app

Comment: Have a look at this [**answer**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42460418/angular-2-ng2-bootstrap-parent-component-call-modal-show-in-child-component-n/42463516#42463516) and if u r not satisfied still, we will fix this ngx modal

Comment: was my answer help ful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have required to open your modal with

```
<button (click)="myModal.open()">open my modal</button>
<modal #myModal>
    <modal-header>
        <h1>Modal header</h1>
    </modal-header>
    <modal-content>
        Hello Modal!
    </modal-content>
    <modal-footer>
      <button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="myModal.close()">&times;</button>
    </modal-footer>
</modal>
```

Comment: i get an error in the console ".open is not a function"

Comment: Now, i am not getting any error but the button is inactive so when i press, nothing happens

Comment: make sure you have followed the procedure to install and load the package [ngx-modal](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-modal).

Comment: hi how can i catch an event on close of the modal either clicked outside of the modal or esc button or close button? thanks @RomanC

Answer (score 0):

Following are your mistakes

1. You are trying to use the below line similar to the Traditional Bootstrap Modal, which is wrong as the usual one works with jQuery and Bootstrap.js

   ```
   <button class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="modal" 
            data-target="#myModal">Open</button>
   ```
2. You are using id to define a name to the modal component which is also invalid in the case of typescript and angular2

   ```
   <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
   ```

**Solution:** Replacing the lines in the below code, will work as expected for ngx-modal.

```
import {Component, NgModule} from '@angular/core'
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser'
import {ModalModule} from "ngx-modal";
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>
      <h2>Hello {{name}}</h2>
      <div class="row">
    <button (click)="myModal.open()">open my modal</button>
    <modal #myModal>
        <modal-header>
            <h1>Modal header</h1>
        </modal-header>
        <modal-content>
            Hello Modal!
        </modal-content>
        <modal-footer>
            <button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="myModal.close()">close</button>
        </modal-footer>
    </modal>
</div>
    </div>
  `,
})
export class App {
  name:string;
  constructor() {
    this.name = 'Angular2'
  }
}

@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule,ModalModule ],
  declarations: [ App ],
  bootstrap: [ App ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

**[LIVE DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/8x34JbEhYdVms4iYLRvM?p=preview)**

Comment: @RomanC If you can see the plunker, I have used **ngx-modal** which was OPs expectation