# Angular2 - Open modal from another component

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular2-components

I have two components: login and forgot-password, the second one is a child component of the first. The forgot-password template is a modal but the action that opens this modal is in login template.

Here is the forgot-password template:

```
<div bsModal #forgotpassword="bs-modal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="forgotpasswordLabel" aria-hidden="true">
....
</div>
```

In login template I try to open this modal like this:

```
<a class="mt help-block" (click)="forgotpassword.show()">Forgot your password?</a>
```

When I click in this link the console returns:

```
EXCEPTION: Error in ./Login class Login - inline template:26:18 caused by: Cannot read property 'show' of undefined
```

I tested including this link in forgot-password template and it worked. I believe I must indicate this modal is in the other component but I didn't figure out how.

Comment: there are many ways to do it. but I guess this would be the easiest way refer this link. http://learnangular2.com/viewChild/

Comment: Can you have a look at this answer [**here**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42460418/angular-2-ng2-bootstrap-parent-component-call-modal-show-in-child-component-n)

Comment: Yes! That solved my problem! Thanks!