# Extending ngx-bootstrap ModalDirective with my own template

Tags: angular, ngx-bootstrap

I wish to extend ngx-bootstrap modal and use my own template, how would I go about doing this? End product should be custom component that behaves just like ngx-bootstrap's modal but it should predefined template.

```
@Injectable()
@Component({
    selector: 'register-patient',
    templateUrl: 'register-patient.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['register-patient.component.scss']
})
export class RegisterPatientComponent extends ModalDirective {
    // constructor, my own methods etc.
}
```

seems like promising start. When I open dialog though, I see only standard backdrop and nothing else. I suspect my template file needs to include some special directive or something but I can't find any topic online. I also can't find original ngx-bootstrap html templates which I could copy and modify. What do I need to include in `register-patient.component.html` for this to work?

Answer (score 0):

Why you want to do so. You can achieve what you want with parent component controlling the child modal component. Check this stackoverflow question [Similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42460418/angular-2-ng2-bootstrap-modal-inside-child-component-called-from-parent-componen)