# How to open an ng-Bootstrap-Modal that is a child component?

Tags: angular, bootstrap-modal, angular-components, ng-bootstrap, ng-bootstrap-modal

I'm new with Angular and I have some doubts about **Modals** with **ng-Bootstrap**. I've been able to open Modals that are in the same component and they work fine, an example is this one:

**Link:**

```
<a (click)="openAbout(contentAbout)" class="nav-link">About</a>
```

**Click event:**

```
  openAbout(contentAbout) {
    this.modalService.open(contentAbout, { centered: true, scrollable: true });
  }
```

**Modal:**

```
<ng-template #contentAbout let-c="close" let-d="dismiss">
  <div class="modal-header">
      <h4 class="modal-title" id="modal-primary-title">About us</h4>
      <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close" (click)="d('Cross click')">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
      </button>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body centered">
    <h2>Gravity Now!</h2>
    <p>It is a platform designed for Space Apps Challenge and the Challenge Gravity Map, Earth Watch category and was chosen in the Top 5 of The Most Inspiring Projects of 2014.</p>
    <a href="https://2014.spaceappschallenge.org/awards/#globalawards" target="_blank">
      <img id="spaceLogo" src="./assets/space_apps.png">
    </a>
    <br>
    <img id="supernovaLogo" src="./assets/supernova-logo.png">
    <p>Also, you can download our apps.</p>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">
        <a href="https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=tk.supernova.gnow" target="_blank">
          <img class="logo" src="./assets/android.png">
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="col">
        <a href="https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/gravity-now/9nblgggzjlp5" target="_blank">
          <img class="logoWindows" src="./assets/windows.png">
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</ng-template>
```

And it works, however, I'd like to move this modal to a child component because I have 4 Modals and the code looks somehow disorganized, but if I create a new child component, move the modal code to the child and then, I add it to the parent component like this:

```
<app-about></app-about>
```

Nothing happens, since the click doesn't open anything. Does anyone have experience something similar? Do you know what should I change in the click event?

I read even the documentation and I cannot find an example related to my one:

https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/modal/examples

Thanks for any idea.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a couple of changes to take in consideration.

The first step is to register your Modals in the `entryComponents` section of your `app.module.ts`:

```
entryComponents: [
    AboutComponent,
],
```

Next, copy your old Modal to your new component and remove these 2 lines:

```
<ng-template #contentAbout let-c="close" let-d="dismiss">
</ng-template>
```

After, there is a small change in the logic of the click event on how to call it:

This is the new HTML code:

```
<a class="nav-link" (click)="openAbout()">About</a>
```

This is the new TypeScript event:

```
openAbout() {
    //Here you define the name of your component
    this.modalService.open(AboutComponent);
    //This section is if you want to have any variable to initialize
    //compConst.componentInstance.weight = undefined;
}
```

Also, in your new Component, you need to add change your `constructor` and add an instance of `NgbActiveModal`.

```
constructor(public activeModal: NgbActiveModal) { }
```

Another important change is in the logic of closing the modal, it needs to be changed to this:

```
<button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close" (click)="activeModal.dismiss('Cross click')">
    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
</button>
```

You need to change the old: `(click)="d('Cross click')"` to `(click)="activeModal.dismiss('Cross click')"`

And with all these changes it will work like charm. I got some inspiration from here:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uwtgs6

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this but what you can do is that you can emit an event from child to parent.
Try looking out for event emitter in the Angular docs.

Comment: How if the child is invisible? It's a modal, it will be visible until it opens. And Output would emit something if you perform an action from the child itself that I'm not editing or changing anything from it. Also, this is more like a comment than an answer.

Comment: Please check this link once.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42460418/angular-2-ng2-bootstrap-modal-inside-child-component-called-from-parent-componen

Comment: I'll check it, but that's a different library and the behavior might be different.

Comment: You can try to understand the logic though. Whatever works. Cheers.

Comment: I added my solution since it was relatively different from the link.

Answer (score 0):

```
Instead of calling child component in parent view you sould try this.
// if want to pass any value to child (parameter @Input() value in child);
// get back response from child (result @Output() EventEmitter value in child)
openChildComponentModel() {
        const modalRef = this.modalService.open(
            AboutComponent,
            {backdrop: 'static'}
        );
        modalRef.componentInstance.parameter= 'Text';
        modalRef.componentInstance.result.subscribe((response) => {}
        });
    }
```

Comment: Hi Mohsin, should I write a modalService? Or is it a general class? Thanks.

Comment: This general class which contain ref of 'NgbModal'.
import { NgbModal } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

Comment: Thanks! I'll let you know in a couple of hours when I'm back at home.